# Integrating $\int \frac {dx}{\sqrt{4x^{2}+1}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$\int \dfrac {dx}{\sqrt{4x^{2}+1}}$

I've been up to this one for quite a while already, and have tried several ways to integrate it, using substituion, with trigonometric as well as hyperbolic functions. I know(I think) I'm supposed to obtain:

$\dfrac {1}{2}\ln \left| 2\sqrt {x^2 +\dfrac {1}{4}}+2x\right|+c$

However, whatever idea I come up with to try to solve it, it seems I always obtain:

$\dfrac {1}{2}\ln \left| x + \sqrt {x^2 + 1} \right| + c$

Thanks for reading, and hopefully answering too.

Cheers

Yann

Comment: An alternative approach would be $2x=\sinh t$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Use trigonometric substitution and put $$2x = \tan\theta^{(\dagger)}  \implies 2\,dx = \sec^2\theta\,d\theta \iff dx = \frac 12 \sec^2 \theta\,d\theta$$

$(\dagger)\;\;\theta = \arctan(2x)$.

Recall, also, that $\tan^2 \theta + 1 = \sec^2\theta$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $x = \frac{1}{2} \tan\theta$ so that $dx=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\theta d\theta$. Then

$\begin{align*}
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}} &= \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sec^2 \theta}{\sec\theta} d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int\sec\theta d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log|\sec\theta + \tan\theta| + C
\end{align*}$

for some real constant $C$. Note that we assumed $\tan\theta = 2x$, so $\sec\theta = \sqrt{4x^2 - 1}$. Hence,

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}= \frac{1}{2}\log|\sqrt{4x^2-1} + 2x| + C.$$

Comment: I appreciate your work but please use $\LaTeX$ to answer the questions here. Here is the link where you can learn $\LaTeX$ :http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/133248

Comment: I reformatted your (excellent) answer using $\LaTeX$. Of course, it's your post so modify it as you see fit.

Comment: @GammaFunction thanks for edit and sorry as I just start using this website recently so I am still not very familiar with LATEX

Answer (score 6):

Since it hasn't been mentioned yet, one more way to do this integral is via [Euler substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution). Compared to the other two methods already described, this method is probably the most direct means of obtaining the particular form of the anti-derivative mentioned in the OP.

Using an Euler substitution of the first kind, $\sqrt{4x^2+1}=-2x+t$, we have $x=\frac{t^2-1}{4t}$ and $\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1+t^2}{4t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$, and hence:

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}
&=\int\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\cdot\frac{1+t^2}{4t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{2t}\\
&=\frac12\ln{(t)}+\color{grey}{constant}\\
&=\frac12\ln{\left(\sqrt{4x^2+1}+2x\right)}+\color{grey}{constant}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

we have $\int \dfrac {dx}{\sqrt{4x^{2}+1}}=\int \dfrac {x}{x\sqrt{4x^{2}+1}}\,dx$.Now let $1+4x^{2}=u^2$, so we have $xdx=\frac{1}{4}udu$ and so $$\int \dfrac {x}{x\sqrt{4x^{2}+1}}\,dx=\frac{1}{4}\int \dfrac {u}{u\frac{u^2-1}{4}}\,du=\int \dfrac {1}{u^2-1}\,du$$ also $$\int \dfrac {1}{u^2-1}\,du=\frac{1}{2}\int (\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1})\,du=\frac{1}{2}\ln|\frac{u-1}{u+1}|.$$ Therefore $$\int \dfrac {dx}{\sqrt{4x^{2}+1}}=\frac{1}{2}\int (\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1})\,du=\frac{1}{2}\ln|\frac{u-1}{u+1}|+C.$$